# Sample junit test case for spring mvc with resteasy controller application

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, resteasy

I'm trying on spring mvc with resteasy test case, already knew spring mvc test case but can't find sample for spring mvc with resteasy test case! If any one knows plz help me, i'm trying it last few days!

Thanx in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got an sample code and wrote my test case! It's works!
Using TJWSEmbeddedSpringMVCServer, we can write a test case for resteasy-spring mvc controller application!

For sample code use:
http://code.google.com/p/resteasy-springmvc/source/browse/trunk/src/test/java/org/jboss/resteasy/examples/springmvc/ContactsTest.java?spec=svn2&r=2

Cheers!